# Has Wonder Woman ever used the Lasso of Truth on Brainiac?

Tags: dc, comics, wonder-woman, brainiac

Across the DC universe, [Wonder Woman](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Wonder_Woman_(Diana_Prince)) has been shown to use [The Lasso of Truth](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Lasso_of_Truth) on her teammates and enemies as well. Even the big guns like Superman haven't been able to overcome the lasso's compulsion to speak the truth ([Wonder-Woman annual #1](https://www.dccomics.com/comics/wonder-woman-2016/wonder-woman-annual-1)).

[image]
 <sub>*Wonder Woman annual #1*</sub>

So, has Wonder Woman ever used (or has the opportunity) to use the Lasso of Truth on [Brainiac](https://www.dccomics.com/characters/brainiac)? If yes, what was the outcome? Was the lasso able to compel Brainiac to speak the truth?

**PS:** *I'm looking for answers from the comic books. So if your answer comes from the very recent issues (anything within the last few months) of Justice League comics, please put it under spoilers tag.*

Comment: Batman has track record of fooling Lasso of Truth. He once rewrote his certain part of memory which he wanted to hide. Then, Wonder Woman got false information. If Lasso of Truth can work on a robot, then Brianiac can easily do the thing Batman did. It can even export its entire brain data to an external storage device.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

She's used it on him on various occasions. There's no good indication that it does anything other than simply compel him to tell the truth.

[image]
<sub><sup>[Justice League: No Justice #1](https://www.dccomics.com/comics/justice-league-no-justice-2018/justice-league-no-justice-1)</sup></sub>

[image]
<sub><sup>[Kenner Super Powers MiniComic Vol.4 #1](https://www.dccomics.com/comics/super-powers-2016/super-powers-1)</sup></sub>

Comment: I got to read the **No Justice** series. The first one is quite intriguing.